# TypeError when using Whisper AI to transcribe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, transcription, openai-whisper

I want to transcribe an audio file by using Whisper AI.
I learned from an article https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/how-to-run-openais-whisper-speech-recognition-model/
That using python version 3.8.16 and pytorch 1.12.1 would do the job.

I also installed the recent version of ffmpeg

I use jupyter notebook to run my code

```
import sys
print(sys.version)

import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

returns

```
3.8.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb  1 2023, 15:53:35) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
1.12.1
```

Then I used this code to try to trancribe a test audio:

```
import openai
import whisper

openai.api_key = "my open ai key"

audio_file= open(r"C:\Users\Chris\Python scripts\test_audio.mp3", "rb")

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe(audio_file)

print(result)
```

When running this I get the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 9
      6 audio_file= open(r"C:\Users\Chris\Python scripts\test_audio.mp3", "rb")
      8 model = whisper.load_model("base")
----> 9 result = model.transcribe(audio_file)
     11 print(result)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:121, in transcribe(model, audio, verbose, temperature, compression_ratio_threshold, logprob_threshold, no_speech_threshold, condition_on_previous_text, initial_prompt, word_timestamps, prepend_punctuations, append_punctuations, **decode_options)
    118     decode_options["fp16"] = False
    120 # Pad 30-seconds of silence to the input audio, for slicing
--> 121 mel = log_mel_spectrogram(audio, padding=N_SAMPLES)
    122 content_frames = mel.shape[-1] - N_FRAMES
    124 if decode_options.get("language", None) is None:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py:131, in log_mel_spectrogram(audio, n_mels, padding, device)
    129     if isinstance(audio, str):
    130         audio = load_audio(audio)
--> 131     audio = torch.from_numpy(audio)
    133 if device is not None:
    134     audio = audio.to(device)

TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got _io.BufferedReader)
```

What am I missing here to get this to work?

Comment: Looks like you need to convert the audiofile to a numpy array from the error message you have. Did it show this in the example you are working off of?

Comment: I converted it into a numpy array by using a2n.audio_from_file(r"C:\Users\Chris\Python scripts\test_audio.mp3")[0]) it gave a error that it allocated 289 GB of data

Comment: If I was you, I would follow the example exactly and see if you can do it. Then I would try using your own audiofile. Not really sure how else to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import openAI and whisper for me this code work

```
    import openai
    
    openai.api_key = api_key
    
    audio_file_path = "./audio.mp3"
    
    with open(audio_file_path, "rb") as audio_file:
        response = openai.Audio.transcribe(model="whisper-1", engine="whisper",response_format="text", file=audio_file)
    
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `model.transcribe` is of type `Union[str, np.ndarray, torch.Tensor]` - meaning it expects a string (i.e. file path), a numpy array, or a torch tensor. Try passing the file path directly instead of opening it:

```py
import whisper

audio_file= "C:\Users\Chris\Python scripts\test_audio.mp3"

model = whisper.load_model("base")
result = model.transcribe(audio_file)

print(result)
```

Also, since you are working offline, you do not need to set `openai.api_key`.